# Hide Specific Column Data Under Column Group

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, hide, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012.

I currently have a tablix where I have 4 columns underneath a Column Group Indicator: Count of ID's, Avg Business Age, Within Requirements, and currently an unnamed column.

All I'm trying to do is basically hide the column Within Requirements from showing up at all on my report. I try to go into textbox properties and select Hide under visibility, but when I run report...it doesn't slide the unnamed column over and make it look clean.

It basically gives me all 4 columns, but a huge blank white space between Avg Business Age and the unnamed column. Is there a way to hide the Within Requirements column so that when I preview the report it basically doesn't show up and the other 3 columns slide over and come together to look cleaner?

[image: 4 columns under Column Group Indicator]

Comment: Why not just remove it from the dataset, if you are just hiding it?

Comment: Trying to see if I could use results from Within Requirements to calculate my next unnamed column. Is that even something possible or worthwhile to do?

Comment: But I don't want to show Within Requirements.

Comment: To accomplish this you need to modify the `column visibility` property for the column with `Within Requirements` in it. If you just hide the cell itself then it still leaves the column.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @smul86 select your tablix, right click on the column you want to hide -> column visibility -> select hide -> click ok.  You must right click at the top of the column, not on an individual cell for this option to be available.